# AngularJS: Use a route as a filter in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm pretty new to Angular and I have an ng-repeat in a list that I filter by clicking on some tabs. Here is what a tab looks like

```
   <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="$parent.zonefilter=zone.name" class="ng-binding"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> {{ zone.name }}</a>
```

And here's the list :

```
    <div ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter: zonefilter" class="col-lg-4 ng-scope" ng-controller="MonitorCtrl" ng-animate=" 'animate' ">
  <div class="panel panel-primary panel-active">

    <a href="/{{obj.id}}" target="_blank" class="text-center frame frame_white" ng-class="{black:'frame frame_black', white:'frame frame_white'}[obj.background]">
    {{obj.title}}
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

It works just fine, but I'd like to be able to hit this filter directly via a url. How can I set a url like /edit/obj#lobby to have zonefilter set as lobby ?

All I see with routes in the documentation is redirecting to a brand new template and that's not what I want.

I'm sure I look dumb by asking that but well.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you actually want is state management which is more easily accomplished via another project: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

You could also try using the `resolve` property on `$routeProvider` when you're defining your routes in order to inject a specific filter into the current controller which you can then use in the scope

```
$routeProvider.when( 'lobby', {
    controller: 'RoomController',
    resolve: {
        zonefilter: 'lobby'
    }
});

myApp.controller( 'RoomController', function( zonefilter ) {
   // zonefilter === 'lobby'
});
```

That may also work, but I would definitely look into ui-router for something like this since it'll be cleaner and easier.

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I was searching for

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for it. I am looking for a very similar solution..